# How to define which bean to autowire in Spring

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have 2 beans of the same type:

```
@Component("beanA")
public class BeanA implements BaseBean {}

@Component("beanB")
public class BeanB implements BaseBean {}
```

This type is used in my service:

```
@Service
public class MyService {

    @Autowired
    private BaseBean baseBean;
}
```

Now I want to use both possible MyService beans in another service

```
@Service
public class AnotherService {

    @Autowired
    private MyService myServiceWithBeanA;

    @Autowired
    private MyService myServiceWithBeanB;
}
```

How can I achieve that? Maybe I should take another approach?

I know how to do it in XML-based beans configuration. How can I do it using annotations?

```
<bean id="AnotherService" class="AnotherService">
    <property name="myServiceWithBeanA" ref="myServiceWithBeanA" />
    <property name="myServiceWithBeanB" ref="myServiceWithBeanB" />
</bean>

<bean id="myServiceWithBeanA" class="MyService">
    <property name="baseBean" ref="beanA" />
</bean>

<bean id="myServiceWithBeanB" class="MyService">
    <property name="baseBean" ref="beanB" />
</bean>

<bean id="beanA" class="BeanA" />
<bean id="beanB" class="BeanB" />
```

Comment: Have a look at [`@Qualifier`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers)

Comment: Did you define MyService only once?

Comment: @Saita Yes, MyService is defined only once. It's body would be the same no matter which BaseBean implementation is injected.

Comment: @QBrute I'm aware of this annotation. I know I could create 2 `MyService` implementations with proper `@Qualifier` and then use `@Qualifier` again in `AnotherService` class but I would like to avoid having duplicated implementation of `MyService`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `MyService` is annotated with `@Service`. This means that it is a singleton - only one instance will be created.

In order to create multiple instances, you need to expose two `@Bean`s via configuration.

```
@Configuration
public class MyServiceConfig {
    @Bean
    public MyService serviceA(@Qualifier("beanA") beanA) {
        return new MyService(beanA);
    }

    @Bean
    public MyService serviceB(@Qualifier("beanB") beanB) {
        return new MyService(beanB);
    }
}
```

`MyService` would become

```
public class MyService {
    private BaseBean baseBean;

    public MyService(BaseBean baseBean) {
        this.baseBean = baseBean;
    }
}
```

You can then pass all of these to the other service with qualifiers

```
@Service
public class AnotherService {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("serviceA")
    private MyService myServiceWithBeanA;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("serviceB")
    private MyService myServiceWithBeanB;
}
```

Comment: That's exactly the answer I needed. Thank you!

Comment: @bartex9 Sure, happy to help

Comment: @Michael where is "serviceA" and "serviceB" declared ?

Comment: @PaulMarcelinBejan By the methods `public MyService serviceA(...)` and `public MyService serviceB(...)` in MyServiceConfig.

Comment: ok, so is linked to the name of the method. thanks!

Comment: @PaulMarcelinBejan Yeah. The name of the Spring bean is the name of the method. But if you want the name to be different, you can use `@Bean(name = "someName")` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `@Qualifier` annotation you can specify which bean you want to autowire.

```
@Service
public class AnotherService {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("beanA")
    private MyService myServiceWithBeanA;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("beanB")
    private MyService myServiceWithBeanB;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: In my case there's only one bean of `MyService`. `beanA` and `beanB` names refer to `BaseBean` implementations. In `AnotherService` I am autowiring `MyService` beans.

Comment: `@Qualifier("beanA")` will not work, since `beanA` is a `BaseBean`, not a `MyService`

Answer (score 0):

In your `xml` bean definition add the these tags `<qualifier value="name"/>`.

```
<bean id="myServiceWithBeanA" class="MyService">
    <qualifier value="A"/>
    <property name="baseBean" ref="beanA" />
</bean>

<bean id="myServiceWithBeanB" class="MyService">
    <qualifier value="B"/>
    <property name="baseBean" ref="beanB" />
</bean>
```

And then you can get them by using `Qualifier` annotation like this:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("A")
private MyService myServiceWithBeanA;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("B")
private MyService myServiceWithBeanB;
```

You also can do more stuff than that.
Have a look at the documentation on the following link:
[Qualifier documentaiton](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers)

Comment: The question is how can I do it without having `xml` bean definition.

Comment: From the question "How can I do it using annotations?"

Answer (score -1):

Not everything can be done with annotations. In cases where you need to create multiple instance of a bean but with different arguments you have to fallback to [@Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.m3/reference/html/creating-bean-definitions.html) and define those beans as you would in the XML config.

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public MyService myServiceWithBeanA(BeanA beanA) {
        return new MyService(beanA);
    }

    @Bean
    public MyService myserviceWithBeanB(BeanB beanB) {
        return new MyService(beanB);
    }

}
```

Now just tell `AnotherService` to expect `MyService` twice with matching bean names as name of the bean defining method is its default qualifier.

```
@Service
public class AnotherService {

    @Autowired
    private MyService myServiceWithBeanA;

    @Autowired
    private MyService myServiceWithBeanB;
}
```